# How to set default selected values in angular material selection lists?

Tags: angular, listview, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to set default selected values in an angular material selection list using angular reactive forms.

I set the default array of values in constructor using `setValue()` method for the selection list form control.

The problem is that I have this error in the console: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Previous value: 'aria-selected: false'. Current value: 'aria-selected: true'`

I let you here the link to stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu2pcy

Comment: [Surround it with a timeout](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu2pcy-1p3tld?file=app/list-selection-example.ts) for a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find detailed explanations about that exception in [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4). One technique to eliminate the exception is to force change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`.

A [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu2pcy-7twfaf) working example based on your code using `ChangeDetectorRef`.